# Private video streaming for Amazon CloudFront in ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, video-streaming, rtmp, amazon-cloudfront

### How does signed URLs work for streamed videos in Amazon CloudFront?

I'm using [aws_cf_signer](https://github.com/stlondemand/aws_cf_signer) gem, but can't get signed urls work for rtmp streamed mp4-file. For static files, like text.txt it works fine, but not when I have streaming distribution.

#### Example:

I have file named test.mp4 so how do I get signed url out of `signer.sign()`?

E.g. `signed_url = signer.sign('rtmp://xyz.cloudfront.net/test', :ending => Time.now + 3600)` does not produce working url. I have tested URLs with VLC player and `rtmpdump`

The distribution itself is created with [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto) like this:

> stream_dist = cf.create_streaming_distribution(origin=origin,
>   enabled=True,
>               trusted_signers=["Self"],
>               comment="test distribution")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [AWS: Restricting End User Access](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RestrictingAccessPrivateContent.html#CreatingSignedURL) doc, the format for signed RTMP urls is different from HTTP:

> With HTTP, a full URL uniquely describes an object. You can include the URL 
>   in the signature. The content of a streaming distribution, however, cannot always 
>   be described by a valid URL. In a streaming distribution, you only use the stream 
>   name to create a signature. For example, if your stream including the signature is:
>
> `example/mp3_name.mp3?Expires=1258237200&Signature=TBD&Key-Pair-Id=PK12345EXAMPLE`
>
> The value for RESOURCE is:
>
> `example/mp3_name`
>
> For streaming distributions, you do not include a prefix, such as mp3: or mp4:, 
>   for the resource name in the policy.
>
> Also, when referencing an MPEG file, you might have to omit the file extension for 
>   the URL enclosed in the signature. For example, you use mp3_name instead of mp3_name.mp3.

I'm not sure whether aws_cf_signer gem supports signing RTMP urls, unfortunately.  If you find out, please let me know!

Comment: I got it working earlier, but forgot to update this question. So yes the answer is correct and by definition aws_cf_signer "supports" rtmp signing as only the stream name is needed for signing rtmp resource. E.g. if you have bucket named "test" and streamed file "video.mp4" located in bucket root then the string to sign is simply "video.mp4". It's unfortunate that this behavior is so poorly documented.

Comment: Does the bucket need special permissions? I've been trying to solve this for a few days now and the poor documentation doesn't help trying to troubleshoot.